# Referencing a .php file from an html img src tag

Tags: php, html, image

In my getimage.php file, I have a function that returns an image and an echo statement

```
function getPicture(){
}
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo getPicture();
```

Then in my index.html I have the following code

```
<body>
        <img src="getimage.php" />
</body>
```

Now obviously I know im doing something wrong, as in the html its a broken picture. I am assuming that setting the src as a .php file doesnt actually execute getimage.php

Any ideas/help?

Thanks!

```
function getPicture()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'image url');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer XXXX'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
        $picture = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $picture;
    }
```

Comment: What does `getPicture()` return?

Comment: your function does NOTHING but output an http image header. since there's no actual image data (e.g. the bytes in a gif/jpg/png file), there's nothing useful received on the client side and you get a broken image. You're basically going "i'm going to send you a picture", and then walking away and doing nothing.

Comment: You need to do get_file_contents() of the image, after sending the header

Comment: Did you check request/response in your browser dev tools?

Comment: I added my getPicture function for all of you lovely downvoters. Thanks for looking @ my question

Comment: I wasn't a lovely down-voter before, but I am considering it now that you have called them out. Folks are just trying to help you get to a better, more complete question where you can get actual help instead of speculation.

Comment: Have you tried accessing this php file directly from your browser? that way you will still get the php errors outputted to the screen at least. putting it straight in a ing tags mutes these errors as they are interpreted as image data.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Do whatever you want. 
Vincent Thanks! Ill try that now and post the result

Comment: @VincentDuprez so when I go to the getimage.php directly it displays the image fine, I just need to figure out how to reference the php file correctly in html so that it shows the picture within the img tag

Comment: Then if the image is displayed fine, there is nothing wrong with your code. referencing php images is very common, especially in e-mails to be able to track image reads, the image is opened with parameters indicating who is opening the image. So nothing wrong with your code, should be a simple path mistake and I'm afraid Rick D's answer is in that case could be a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the location of getimage.php, you will probably have to specify the relative URL path, such as

```
<img src="/getimage.php" />
```

Assuming getimage.php is at the root of your website.

Comment: I verified this on a local site of mine. At the doc root I created getimage.php with your above code, so I could access it in the browser with http://getimage.local/getimage.php. src="getimage.php" doesn't work, but src="/getimage.php" does

Comment: starting a path with a / is an absolute path... you inverted relative and absolute

Comment: @VincentDuprez - starting a path with `/` is relative to the document root.  An absolute path is the *full* path (`http://domain.ext/foobar`, in the case of HTTP)

Comment: Yeah, "root relative" is the term I've seen for "/foo/bar". "foo/bar" is relative, "http://example.com/foo/bar" is absolute.